# apache geode 9.0.3 off heap region, xml configuration

Tags: xml, in-memory-database, geode, off-heap

How can i declare a region to be Off heap, via xml configuration
using apache geode 9.0.3

my xml configuration is in  server-cache.xml  as.

```
<!DOCTYPE cache PUBLIC
 "-//GemStone Systems, Inc.//GemFire Declarative Caching 8.0//EN"
 "http://www.gemstone.com/dtd/cache8_0.dtd">
  <cache>

   <region name="regionA">
      <region-attributes off-heap="true"/>
      <region-attributes data-policy="partition"/>
   </region>

 </cache>
```

I get this error

```
org.apache.geode.cache.CacheXmlException: While reading Cache XML file:/server-cache.xml. Error while parsing XML, caused by org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 14; columnNumber: 43; Attribute "off-heap" must be declared for element type "region-attributes".
```

I read this

Mark regions whose entry values should be stored off-heap by setting the off-heap region attribute to true Configure other region attributes uniformly for all members that host data for the same region.

from 
http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/geode/managing/heap_use/off_heap_management.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your xml schema for this new attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <cache
    xmlns="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache 
    http://geode.apache.org/schema/cache/cache-1.0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

  <region name="regionA">
    <region-attributes off-heap="true"/>
    <region-attributes data-policy="partition"/>
  </region>
</xml>
```

Although despite this, the off-heap attribute is still not picked up. I file a Geode JIRA for this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GEODE-2841